# p:commandButton not triggering actionlistener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

OK, I've read all of the posts about this issue and I can't find it.  My situation is super easy - all I'm doing is using Primefaces 3.3.1 with JSF 2.1 to render a login page.  Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>ACME Systems - Home Page</title>
    <style>
    .noBorders tr, .noBorders td {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:panel id="mainPanel"
        style="height: 106px; height: auto !important; margin: 0 auto; min-height: 106px; position: relative; width: 960px; z-index: 100;">
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <p:panel header="Secure Login"
                style="padding-bottom: 40px; width: 380px;">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="noBorders">
                    <h:outputText value="Username:" />
                    <p:inputText id="username" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Username is required." title="Username"
                        value="#{LoginBean.username}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Password:" />
                    <p:password id="password" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Password is required"
                        value="#{LoginBean.password}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login"
                    actionListener="#{LoginBean.login}"
                    style="margin-top: 5px; float: right;" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The actionlistener on the commandbutton is not firing.  If I change it to a h:commandbutton all is well.  I would prefer using the primefaces tag only because it uses the theme.  If I use h: then I'll need to grab the css.  Any ideas?  One other thing, if I drop a h:commandbutton right before the primefaces button, and use it to do the initial trigger, the primefaces button works from then on:P  Go figure!

Comment: I fix it somehow.  I added an update= to the commandbutton and set it to the outerpanel.  I also added the label attribute to the input fields.  Was adding the update attribute what fixed it or the that and adding an id to the outer panel?  Bizarre.

Comment: You are indeed not updating the UI after executing the action, so the enduser would get no feedback at all (unless the action method uses `ExternalContext#redirect()` or `NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`). How exactly did you confirm that the action listener is not firing? Did you put a debug breakpoint on the actual method or added a logger in there? Or did you just conclude that based on that you didn't get any UI feedback, without looking at the HTTP traffic and code execution?

Comment: I did add a logger and nothing appeared.  That's when I knew I was doing something wrong via the primefaces component.  Maybe a reason why even their showcase examples sometimes use the h tags over their own.  In my case, I wanted to keep everything within the theme, else I would have gone with the h tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since I fixed, going to close this out.  Maybe someone can use this info in the future.  I would make certain you read the code samples Primefaces (or any framework) and use their exact code until you feel you have a grasp on it.  After using JSF for 6 years, I still haven't figured everything out like BalusC:-)